# How to check whether user logged in wordpress site from Yii?

Tags: php, wordpress, yii, authentication

In a my current project, I want to integrate a module done in Yii with a wordpress site.
The user will login through the wordpress site and moved to the Yii section. I want to check from Yii, whether the user is logged in. Yii will be installed with in the root directory of wordpress and both the sites will hosted under same domain. like

```
http:://www.main-wp-site.com
http:://yiimodule.main-wp-site.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution!!
All I have to do is include the `wp-load.php` file in the `index.php` of Yii and after that, I will be able to use all the wordpress functions, including `is_user_logged_in()`

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the Wordpress Function reference [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/) . The function you're looking for is `is_user_logged_in()` which returns true or false if the current user has a valid Wordpress login.